# How to ensure smarter indentation in Vim after multiline function header?

Tags: vim, whitespace, indentation

I am using Javascript with typescript if it matters (I don't think it does for this question for reasons that I will explain later) and I have the following code:

```
veryLongFunctionName(arg1: type,
                     arg2: type,
                     arg3: type) {
/* ... */
}
```

But when I try to make a new line in the function body it auto indents to one indent past the `arg3`'s column in the header. For example, since my indentation is set to two spaces, typing `osomeCode<ESC>` when my cursor is on `arg3` results in the following.

```
veryLongFunctionName(arg1: type,
                     arg2: type,
                     arg3: type) {
                       someCode
/* ... */
}
```

Which is obviously not what I would like, I want its indentation level to be based upon the indentation of the function header itself. Even when I remove the typescript and javascript syntax plugins from my .vimrc, it bases its indentation on the wrong line like so.

```
veryLongFunctionName(arg1: type,
                     arg2: type,
                     arg3: type) {
                     someCode
/* ... */
}
```

Only when I completely remove the `filetype plugin indent on` line from my .vimrc does the cursor not auto-indent to the column of `arg3` (because it doesn't indent at all).

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: You might like to look at `:help cinoptions`